# SQL Get rows from table 1 that dont exist in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not really a SQL expert so I was wondering if there is a query that can do this. I have 2 SQL tables, table1 and table2. I need to get an output of rows from table 1 that does not exist in table 2. For example if the data in column 1 row 1 is not in table 2. Is there  a way to do this? TIA

I tried the following:

```
 select dbo.table1.TIN
 From dbo.table1 as T1
 where not exists (select * from dbo.table2 as T2 where T1.TIN = T2.TIN)
```

Getting error

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.table1.TIN" could not be bound.

Comment: Yes there are many ways.. left join, not exists, except...

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks added what I tried above but getting error The multi-part identifier "dbo.table1.TIN" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have an issue with the table alias

```
select T1.TIN
From dbo.table1 as T1
where not exists (select * from dbo.table2 as T2 where T1.TIN = T2.TIN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.tin
from table1 tin
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.tin = t2.tin);
```